# c - can't compile with <sys/times.h> ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu

I have 64bit ubuntu installed, and I am trying to compile a code with times.h however I keep getting `sys/times.h No such file or directory`

What I have tried so far
1. installing libc6-dev-i386, g++-multili, and libc6 and libc6-dev (Even though it is already installed)
2. I swapped `<sys/times.h>` to `</usr/include/sys/times.h>` and now I am getting `features.h No such file or directory error`

Question:
It is weird how it accepts `</usr/include/sys/times.h>` instead of `<sys/times.h>`, and help?

EDIT: I can access times.h, if it matters

Comment: That's probably because the header is named `sys/time.h`. Singular `time`, and not plural `times`.

Comment: @StoryTeller [It is](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/times.h.html)

Comment: Well, I learned something. And it includes how not to name ones header files.

Comment: What are the permissions on that file? If the compiler can't open it for reading, it cannot include it.

Comment: @StoryTeller lrwxrwxrwx

Comment: So it's a soft link!? What happens when you follow it? Does the pointee file exists and readable?

Comment: I pretty confused if @StoryTeller is right or wrong because `sys/times.h` and `sys/time.h` are both legit header.

Comment: @narusin Yes, but I am talking about times.h not time.h

Comment: @narusin - Well, I'm obviously wrong in assuming the OP misspelled the file name :)

Comment: @StoryTeller Oh I just checked it is -rw-r--r--

Comment: gcc -I /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ comp.c works for me (ubuntu server 14.04 64 bits here), have you tried adding the paths with -I?

Comment: To test you can add the locations to your CPATH variable. Use export CPATH=$CPATH:/your/new/path:/your/other/new/path:(any other path, just use : as a separator) PS: it will set the CPATH for that user and that session, so you need to execute the make with your user and set it again if you logout and login back. @Barmar Thanks, fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend running:

```
$ locate /sys/time.h | grep include
```

Using the output you can determine what to do next:

- If there is a file named `/usr/include/<x86_64 or i386>-linux-gnu/sys/time.h`, then simply run: `$ sudo ln -s /usr/include/<x86_64 or i386>-linux-gnu/sys /usr/include/sys`. This will direct the compiler to the right file if it checks . This seems to be what you are doing manually.
- If there is no relevant output, then try downloading build-essential. It may be that something else is missing. `$ sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Let me know if this helps!